# Tortoise SVN files locked issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, libreoffice, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Tortoise SVN usually denies my commits saying that I have to clean locks.

I run the "clean up" command through the GUI and it works, but it annoys me having to do this so often.

It happens after saving edited LibreOffice documents, even when LibreOffice app is closed.

I have LibreOffice's lock files extensions (.~lock and .odt#) on the svn:ignore property of my repository.

My OS is Windows 10 and I have the latest Tortoise SVN version installed. The server runs the latest version of Visual SVN Server.

I also have the latest version of LibreOffice installed.

But its not a matter of versions, because it started happening some months ago, but now more frequently.

What can I do to avoid needing the cleanup command?

Edit: it seems that KeePass is the problem.
I run KeePass opening a database that is inside my repository.
When I try to commit (and fails due locks), it has the database file opened, but it isnt modified though.

Is there any workaround to avoid closing the database and succesfully commit?

Comment: Do you store this SVN working copy locally or on a network share?

Comment: Locally. My client pc has it's Tortoise SVN repositories on the main disk, where the OS is installed.
The same happens on the server with the Visual SVN repositories.

Comment: This client-side problem occurs because you run the `svn` client operations that change your versioned LibreOffice files when they are open in LibreOffice. The problem shouldn't occur if you ensure that you run SVN client operations when LibreOffice is closed. It seems that LibreOffice opens files in exclusive access mode (I'm going to double-check this with procmon later), so another program such as `svn.exe` or TortoiseSVN cannot update the file at that time, and the SVN working copy becomes locked and requires a cleanup. This problem is reproducible with LibreOffice and MS Office.

Comment: I tried it but couldn't reproduce it. Do you have the latest LibreOffice version?
I also assume you saved the document before trying SVN commit

Comment: Yes, I have the latest LibreOffice version. I don't have access to my testing machine now, but I remember this repro: 1. Open an modify an ODT file in LibreOffce (don't commit). 2. Keep LibreOffice open and run the SVN Revert command in TortoiseSVN. SVN will display a 'permission denied' error message because it cannot write into the ODT file and the working copy will become locked. Running `svn cleanup` resolved the issue.

Comment: Nice, I could reproduce it.
This should be the right answer, but is there any workaround?
Also, if LibreOffice keep locking a file after closing it, then I should report it as a LibreOffice's bug, shouldn't I?

Comment: I have updates on this. It seems that KeePass is the problem (see my edit).
I have KeePass app with a database opened, and the opened database is inside my repository.
Can I avoid this and commit the other files without having to close KeePass?
My database file isn't modified though.

Comment: Just thinking: maybe there is a way to config SVN (maybe through repository properties) to automatically cleaning locks on some internal folder.

Comment: thank you for the info about keepass, but it seems that this is another issue. I'm looking into this cleanup issue, please give me additional time to process this.